# Linear Map Operation Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to determine the notation for a linear map operation that my teacher is using. One particular example is in the homework problem I am doing, in which **T**∈ L(U,V) and **S** ∈ L(V,W). I am asked to suppose that **S** **T** is injective and show that this means that T is also injective. I may be able to do this, but I'm struggling to understand exactly what the notation **S** **T** means. I seem to remember it meaning a composition of S and T, but I'm uncertain of this fact, being that I thought this was notated as **S**◦**T**. I'm wondering what this means.

Comment: It means composition.

Comment: $ST$ means exactly the same thing as $S\circ T$, and is used substantially more often.